# How to disable browser back button in Oracle ADF

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I know. I should not do this. But...

I need to disable browser back button in an ADF web application. I've tried with this code in the initialize javascript function on a jspx (we can call main.jspx):

```
window.history.forward(1);
```

The back button is not disabled but if I click it after visiting main page (e.g. from the page after main to the main page) it returns to the second page. I would to diasble the back button at all. Is it possible? If you know something specifically for ADF application (also without using javascript) the answer is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: short answer, no: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1104731. Though there are some good suggestions in that discussion.

Comment: Only thing I could think to do would be to open a new tab/window, but that would probably be more of an annoyance than it would be worth.

Comment: @vcsjones Yes I've read that page (and all others placed in the first 4 or 5 result pages on Google) but I cannot modify my application using dynamic region pattern for many reasons.

Comment: @Travesty3 Thanks for the comment, but in this way I should open a new window and close the first, and sincerely I think that is no the right (and shortest) way.

Comment: @Baduel: I agree. Not to mention, attempting to close the first window would likely produce a message to the client telling them that the webpage is trying to close the window and asking them if they want to do this...which would definitely cause confusion, so I don't suggest it at all. Basically, as you already mentioned in your post, you should not do this.

Comment: The only way to really do it (extensive XHR frameworks aside), is to use JavaScript's location.replace() for every single interaction, which means you can't POST anything.  You are insane to think you need it or it solves anything.  Tell us why you need to disable it and perhaps we can tell you the correct solution (e.g. POST->redirect->GET).

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski The reason why I want to disable the back button is that usually if the user uses it in the ADF web app, the result is an internal server error (500).

Comment: Yeah, the correct solution would be to fix your internal server error, sorry. :(

Comment: Yes, you're right. I try to analyze in deep my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

I have two pages: page1.jspx and page2.jspx. I have defined a control-flow-case in adfc-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<adfc-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller" version="1.2">
  <view id="page1">
    <page>/page1.jspx</page>
  </view>
  <view id="page2">
    <page>/page2.jspx</page>
  </view>
  <control-flow-rule id="__1">
    <from-activity-id>page1</from-activity-id>
    <control-flow-case id="__2">
      <from-outcome>navigate</from-outcome>
      <to-activity-id>page2</to-activity-id>
    </control-flow-case>
  </control-flow-rule>
</adfc-config>
```

So by `action="navigate"` I will be navigated to the page 2 from page 1.

Now the page1.jspx is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <f:view>
        <af:document title="Page 1" id="d1">
            <af:form id="f1">
                <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
                    <f:facet name="center">
                        <af:commandLink action="navigate" id="cl1">
                            Navigate
                        </af:commandLink>
                    </f:facet>
                </af:panelStretchLayout>
                <af:resource type="javascript">
                    var registerDisableBackButton = function () {
                        disableBackButton();
                        window.onload = disableBackButton();
                        window.onpageshow = function (event) {
                            if (event.persisted) {
                                disableBackButton()
                            }
                        }
                        window.onunload = function () {
                            void (0);
                        }
                    }

                    var disableBackButton = function () {
                        window.history.forward();
                    }

                    var onLoadEvent = function(event) {
                        registerDisableBackButton();
                    }
                </af:resource>                
            </af:form>
            <af:clientListener method="onLoadEvent" type="load"/>
        </af:document>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

After navigating to page2.jspx if you click the back button you will be again redirected to the page 2.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try your solution. Anyway with this solution the back button is not disabled but it only redirect to the same page.

Comment: Yes, this will not disable the back button. You can't disable it programmatically.